# Use storyboard from dependent project in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, bundle

I have one XCode project and an iOS framework configured as a dependent project. I have created a storyboard inside my dependent project. However, when I try to load this storyboard from the main project, I am getting:

```
Could not find a storyboard named 'MyLibStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle.
```

I have configured my iOS framework using this tutorial: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework.

This is a code used to load the storyboard:
https://gist.github.com/poiuytrez/5831043

Comment: if you look at the application package (the app built by Xcode), does that storyboard appear anywhere in there?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Where can I find it? The file under product is in red.

Comment: Build it for the device and then the file under project will turn to black (and can be opened up in the Finder).

Comment: Double check the spelling of "MyLibStoryboard", maybe it is "MyLibStoryBoard", I got same issue before.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The storyboard does not appear in the application package. How do I make sure to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Debug the app by looking into the app generated by XCode. Check if the storyboard or bundle is present. (Thank you Micheal)
2. The bundle generated by MyLib was not present
3. Build the bundle using the target MyLibResources
4. Drag and drop the bundle in XCode in the main project.